# .Net Core dependency injection manually dispose object created using the implementationFactory Func

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection

Is there a way to dispose objects after creating them using the implementationFactory? Like so:

```
   services.AddTransient(x => {
    var objectA = new ObjectA(); //objectA needs to be disposed after the use of objectB
    
    return objectA.ObjectB;
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the only proper way right?

```
services.AddTransient(x => new ObjectA());

services.AddTransient(x => {
var objectA = x.GetService<ObjectA>();

return objectA.ObjectB;
});
```

Comment: Correct. You figured it out before I had a chance to respond. Good going.

Comment: Be careful with disposable transient registrations. When resolved from the root scope/container they might cause memory leaks. Only resolve disposable transients from an `IServiceScope` or inject them into a Singleton.

Comment: @Steven can u elaborate on that?

Comment: I wrote quite extensively about this topic [here](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-15/section-15-2-2).